# Flutter in app purchase iOS not testable in testfly?

Tags: flutter

I have already an iOS app in production, but I have change a little the purchase part. I don't remember or found if it's normal that I can't test a purchase in testfly or in debug mode/release mode.

The id purchase is detected and the product is display. My purchase test work on Android when I clic on the product, I see pop up to test a purchase. But on iOS when I clic on product I have nothing. In debug the purchase is call but no pop up to validate purchase to test, and no more information about errors.

sandbox is activated
sandboxTesting=true;

On my device setting-> itunes Store and app Store-> I have my app id add in sandbox

In app purchase is add on xcode signing and capabilities

Other observation I remember that before I had pop up to add user id and password to connect, I now I don't know why, I don't have the apple connect pop up.

The only things I did, is to try to upgrade flutter, and downgrade ( because some bug) to return to initiale version who is in production. I even try to return to the initial flutter release ( who expected to work) and I have same problem...

I try to create a new flutter projet to test purchase example from flutter package, and use my current bundle id to display my product. It's display but I have same problem : no connection pop up, no purchase pop up. nothing... but purchase is display, found, and all processus (Xcode, appstore connect, testfly .. is valid.

So I'm little afraid to publish without testing.

Before use time machine to backup all my mac before all this bug, I would have your opinion about this

Thank you

Comment: I have the response: I launch production without testing and it’s work. So I don’t know why I can test in testflight mode

Comment: I would recommend using Carbon Copy to create a bootable back up of your mac instead of time machine. I would also recommend doing the backup to an external HD so can boot from it and it work very similar to an native, internal HD experience.